# Workflow runs fine sometimes, errors out at the start other times

Tags: workflow

I have a SharePoint workflow called "Associated Users".  In this workflow I combine up all of the user pickers into one person / group.  I also find the manager of each one of those users and add them to an associated users managers field.

This workflow runs fine 75% of the time, other times it errors out before it even starts.  I have tested this by Logging to the workflow history list as the first line, and after each step.  I see no rhyme or reason as to why it is erroring out.  But the error returned is:

> The workflow could not update the item, possibly because one or more columns for the item require a different type of information.

I combine up all the user information in a string: `User ID Number;#Display Name` and use that field for a view.

I have tried logging each step to determine where the error is and nothing at all is logging.  So this is telling me it is erroring out before the first step.  How is this possible?  All other attached workflows run fine, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your workflow is trying to update the list item before the user's lock has been released. Add a "Pause for 1 minute" step into your workflow before updating any fields on the item so that the system has enough time to release the lock.